# Power Query Pivot loses rows

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to replicate in `Get & Transform` something that is easily done in Excel Pivot Tables.  But when I try to Pivot the Category column, I only get a single row.

**Original Data**

```
| Course         | Category |
|----------------|----------|
| English        | NL       |
| Mathematics    | CCA      |
| Social Studies | STS      |
| Social Studies | SS       |
| History        | STS      |
| History        | CCA      |
| Physics        | STS      |
| Geology        | SS       |
| Geology        | CCA      |
```

In Excel, I can easily generate a desired Pivot Table by dragging:

- Course to the Rows area
- Category to the Columns area
- Category to the Values area

[image]

But if I try to Pivot Category column in `Get and Transform`, the new columns are created, but all of the counts are summarized; not the counts per course.  (And if I choose `Don't Aggregate`, I get an error.

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such as

**M code:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{" Course         ", type text}, {" Category ", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {" Course         "}, {{"Count", each _, type table}}),
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {" Course         ", " Category "}, {"Count. Course         ", "Count. Category "}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Count", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Count"[#"Count. Category "]), "Count. Category ", "Count. Course         ", List.Count)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

**Result:**

[image: Image of query]

**Step 3:**

[image: Step2]

**Step 5:**

[image: Step 5]

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation.  (More complicated than the old Pivot table method, but more flexible).  I stumbled on the Group By, but would not have found the Expand, in the UI.

Comment: I have a feeling there is a neater way but this is the way I remembered.

Comment: Is there a way of applying a random custom number format to the counts within PQ?  e.g; `"X";;;` so as to suppress the 0's, and display the positive counts as **X**

Comment: Oh, never mind.  I found the `Replace Values` button

Comment: Ok. Let me know otherwise.